OpenXml Excel replace string in a cell with formatted text
This is what I did, and it works good in plain text
using var Doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(CXmlDoc.GetExecutingPath () + "Test.xlsx", true);
var nDoc = Doc.Clone(CXmlDoc.GetExecutingPath() + "Test1.xlsx");

var Sst = nDoc.WorkbookPart!.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();

for (var i = 0; i < Sst!.RootElement!.ChildElements.Count(); i++)
{
   var e = Sst.RootElement.ElementAt(i);
   if (!e.InnerText.Contains("test")) continue;

   var NewText = e.InnerText.Replace("test", "NewText");
   e.ReplaceChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(NewText), e.FirstChild);
}


In the excel cell above, if the text within cell is plain text (unformatted), the word test will be replaced correctly. But not working if the text is formatted (bold in this case). See result below:


Not the answer to you question, but it is better to use Path.Combine() to build path to a file, instead of + operator.

Aarrgghh... I forgot to remove the GetExecutingPath, this is my own function, which will ensure it is padded with .

:)  Path.Combine() will care about all such situations.
